# Xamarin app passed NULL surface

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, camera

I'm Wondering if anyone can help me with my current problem.

I am realtivley new to android development, and do not fully understand the way android works with cameras.

Hoping that it is a simple mistake. I have been following the example at [Github - Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader)

Though I have had to modify the example to meet my needs. Primarily writing in C#. And running the barcode detector from a fragment.

When the camera is initialized, gives the following log:

What I believe to the be the main issue is the camera is being passed a null surface. Which is what I do not understand, as the sufaceholder is intialized from what I can tell properly.

Though When I look at it in the debuger, the surfaceframe is empty, and the holder is not valid. I think it might have something to do with being intilazed from a fragment, though I have tried changing the context when the barcodeFragmentActivity is created to Activity.BaseContext. Which made no difference.

```
09-08 23:51:19.597 D/Camera  (30433): app passed NULL surface
09-08 23:51:20.049 D/Mono    (30433): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge  processing to finish
09-08 23:51:20.057 I/art     (30433): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
09-08 23:51:20.099 I/art     (30433): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2409(108KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(8MB) LOS objects, 30% free, 37MB/53MB, paused 245us total 41.233ms
09-08 23:51:20.100 D/Mono    (30433): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 241 objects 245 opaque 5 colors 240 colors-bridged 240 colors-visible 240 xref 12 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.16ms tarjan 0.53ms scc-setup 0.21ms gather-xref 0.02ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.08ms
09-08 23:51:20.100 D/Mono    (30433): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 50.79ms
09-08 23:51:20.100 D/Mono    (30433): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 1024K in use: 633K
09-08 23:51:20.101 D/Mono    (30433): GC_MAJOR: (mature allocation failure) time 33.83ms, stw 36.81ms los size: 10144K in use: 9135K
09-08 23:51:23.320 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
09-08 23:51:23.329 D/InputTransport(30433): Input channel constructed: fd=79
09-08 23:51:23.330 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): setView = DecorView@13a35ae[BarcodeFragmentActivity] touchMode=true
09-08 23:51:23.359 I/Choreographer(30433): Skipped 700 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-08 23:51:23.389 D/ViewRootImpl@4b64d36[MainActivity](30433): mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
09-08 23:51:23.408 D/ViewRootImpl@4b64d36[MainActivity](30433): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
09-08 23:51:23.412 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): dispatchAttachedToWindow
09-08 23:51:23.426 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x7 surface={isValid=true 536149920256} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
09-08 23:51:23.427 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 536149920256} hwInitialized=true
09-08 23:51:23.429 D/mali_winsys(30433): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
09-08 23:51:23.431 I/mono-stdout(30433): MSurfaceView Is not null
MSurfaceView Is not null
09-08 23:51:23.432 I/mono-stdout(30433): Drawing the Layout
Drawing the Layout
09-08 23:51:23.433 I/mono-stdout(30433): StockApp.UI.CameraSource
StockApp.UI.CameraSource
09-08 23:51:23.441 I/mono-stdout(30433): 1440x1080Starting If Ready
1440x1080Starting If Ready
09-08 23:51:23.443 I/mono-stdout(30433): mStartRequested : False ,         mSurfaceAvailabe : True
mStartRequested : False , mSurfaceAvailabe : True
09-08 23:51:23.444 I/mono-stdout(30433): Before Camera Call, @110
Before Camera Call, @110
09-08 23:51:23.825 I/mono-stdout(30433): After Camera Call, @112
After Camera Call, @112
09-08 23:51:23.831 E/ViewRootImpl(30433): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-08 23:51:23.831 E/ViewRootImpl(30433): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-08 23:51:23.882 D/OpenCameraSource(30433): Skipping Frame, Could not Find ByteBuffer Associated with image
09-08 23:51:23.895 D/OpenCameraSource(30433): Skipping Frame, Could not Find ByteBuffer Associated with image
09-08 23:51:23.908 D/OpenCameraSource(30433): Skipping Frame, Could not Find ByteBuffer Associated with image
09-08 23:51:23.919 D/OpenCameraSource(30433): Skipping Frame, Could not Find ByteBuffer Associated with image
09-08 23:51:23.941 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 536149920256} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
09-08 23:51:23.982 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-08 23:51:23.983 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
09-08 23:51:23.984 D/ViewRootImpl@6738e29[BarcodeFragmentActivity](30433): mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 536149920256}
09-08 23:51:23.985 V/InputMethodManager(30433): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4b80f4f nm : StockApp.StockApp ic=null
09-08 23:51:23.985 I/InputMethodManager(30433): [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
09-08 23:51:23.991 D/InputTransport(30433): Input channel constructed: fd=78
09-08 23:51:23.992 D/InputTransport(30433): Input channel destroyed: fd=63
```

I don't want to clutter up this too much, so the code that I think important is  :

```
UI/CameraSource.cs
UI/CameraSourcePreview.cs
BarcodeReader/BarcodeFragmentActivity.cs
BarcodeReader/BarcodeFragment.cs
```

[github - Code](https://github.com/StormMaster12/StockApp/tree/master/StockApp)

Comment: Are you getting any exception for this? and If yes, could you provide the line number of the exception?

Comment: I am not getting an exception, It is just the line passed at the top of the log. The app will run fine, but the preview fragment will be white. With no preview. I know the program is controlling the camera because the torch will turn on if the use flash option is ticked.

Comment: I believe the error is ocouring at line 111. in camera source preview. Didn't read your comment properly the first time.